# Make: only build something if the source's md5 checksum was changed

Tags: makefile

Is it possible to tell `make` to only build a target if it's sources md5 checksum has changed (instead of the edit time)?

I'm using `make` to compile my `.tex` files and I need to prevent it from building everything twice all the time.

I've tried using Scons, but I feel this isn't adaptable to other needs I have.

Comment: I was recently solving a similar issue with makefiles generated using CMake, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600111/how-does-cmake-detect-changed-files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not supported by Make — as you've found out, support for [this feature](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c824.html) is one of the reasons why tools like [Scons](http://www.scons.org/) exist.

I found a manual [recipe](http://www.kolpackov.net/pipermail/notes/2004-September/000011.html) for GNU make, though. Maybe you can use that as a work around.

Comment: the problem with scones is mainly that I would be the only one in my surrounds using that. Nobody I know uses it, I'd feel much more for some makefile hacking (using some if statements perhaps?).

Comment: I would go with Scons regardless, it's a nice system. If it's only for compiling a LaTeX document, then I would use something like [latex-mk](http://latex-mk.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: yes, I just found a solution using latexmk. Thanks for the scones tip. I'll catch up on it when the time is right.

Answer (score 6):

I found 3 ways: From simply

- [Using temporary md5-files](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/ask-mr-make/6795-rebuilding-when-a-files-checksum-changes) over an
- [elegant but unreadable hack](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-make/2009-09/msg00015.html) to
- [patching GNU Make yourself](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-make/2008-04/msg00017.html)

*(from patchy but simple to clean but hard to realize)*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my scons latex and org-mode recipe helps you:

```python
## I need a couple of special builders for my projects
# the $SOURCE replacement only uses the first source file. $SOURCES gives all.
# specifying all source files makes it possible to rerun the build if a single source file changed.
orgexportpdf = 'emacs --batch --visit "$SOURCE" --funcall org-export-as-pdf'
pyxplot = 'pyxplot $SOURCE'
# pdflatex is quite dirty. I directly clean up after it with rm.
pdflatex = 'pdflatex $SOURCE -o $TARGET; rm -f  *_flymake* flymake* *.log *.out *.toc *.aux *.snm *.nav *.vrb'

# build the PhD thesis from emacs org-mode.
Command("doktorarbeit.pdf", "doktorarbeit.org",
        orgexportpdf)

# create plots
Command(["images/comp-t3-s07-tem-boas.png", 
         "images/comp-t3-s07-tem-bona.png"], 
        ["nee-comp.pyx", 
         "nee-comp.txt"],
        pyxplot)

# build my sink.pdf
Command("sink.pdf", 
        ["sink.tex", 
         "images/comp-t3-s07-tem-boas.png", 
         "images/comp-t3-s07-tem-bona.png", 
         "images/bona-marble.png", 
         "images/boas-marble.png"],
        pdflatex)

# My editors leave tempfiles around. I want them gone after a build clean. This is not yet supported!
tempfiles = Glob('*~') + Glob('#*#') + Glob('*.bak')
# using this here would run the cleaning on every run.
#Command("clean", [], Delete(tempfiles))
```

It is the counterpart for my Makefile:

```make
all: doktorarbeit.pdf sink.pdf

sink.pdf : sink.tex images/comp-t3-s07-tem-boas.png images/comp-t3-s07-tem-bona.png images/bona-marble.png images/boas-marble.png
    pdflatex sink.tex
    rm -f  *_flymake* flymake* *.log *.out *.toc *.aux *.snm *.nav *.vrb # kill litter

comp-t3-s07-tem-boas.png comp-t3-s07-tem-bona.png : nee-comp.pyx nee-comp.txt
    pyxplot nee-comp.pyx

# http://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/dy9yt/anyone_know_of_a_script_that_i_can_feed_an/
# http://blog.nguyenvq.com/2010/10/30/bash-batch-script-to-convert-org-mode-file-to-html/comment-page-1/#comment-27013
doktorarbeit.pdf : doktorarbeit.org
    emacs --batch --visit "doktorarbeit.org" --funcall org-export-as-pdf

# this is not what clean is intended to do, but I do it anyway.
clean : 
    rm -f \#* *~ *.bak # kill editor backups

# alternatively run scons. Should I switch to SCons, just put this in all :)
sconsrun : scons
    python scons/bootstrap.py -Q

scons : 
    hg clone https://bitbucket.org/ArneBab/scons
```