# How does CMake detect changed files

Tags: makefile, cmake

I have a "C"/C++ CMake project which works fine. However, I'm sometimes (re)building on a remote cluster where the time is slightly different. This machine runs Linux and I'm building using `make`. I'm wondering if there is some make/CMake way to change how the changes to the files are detected, e.g. to MD5 or diff rather than using timestamps. Otherwise I guess I'd either have to endure the constant `make clean` / `make -j` cycle or have to change my local time every time I'm working with that particular server.

I was poking CMake documentation to see if there is a flag which would change these settings but found none. How would this work on platforms which have no RTC (e.g. Raspberry)?

Comment: CMake doesn't detect changed files **at all**. CMake generates build files, e.g. for `make`, or KDevelop, or Ninja. *Those* tools then detect changed files, each in its own way. Check the relevant tool's documentation. Check with the system admins, time differences should not matter if all systems involved are properly NTP-synced.

Comment: @DevSolar right, I was afraid it went to a lower level. Is there then a way to convince make not to use timestamps? It is a national supercomputing centre, I'm afraid it will be hard to convince them to change the time for me.

Comment: Well, checking timestamps is what `make` is *for*. How do you expect it to do partial rebuilds without a way to detect *what* needs rebuilding?

Comment: You could, of course, sync *your* time to the remote cluster...

Comment: @DevSolar It could cache the MD5s or even the entire files in the `build/src/CMakeFiles/whatever.dir` hierarchy. I guess it should be possible for CMake to do a pass before make and delete/backdate the `.o` files where the source codes changed.

Comment: It's not the **job** of CMake to do anything with / about source files. It **generates** build / project files for whatever build system you intend to use. It's the *build system* that turns sources into binary. CMake has nothing to do with that step. Unless you change one of the CMake configuration files, you can run the build system over and over without CMake being involved in any way. (Like, having used CMake to generate a MSVC solution, you use that solution for your edit / compile / run cycle. It's up to MSVC to handle any file updates. CMake has no stakes in that anymore.)

Comment: `make` works bad with non-local filesystems because of timestamps. You may download all sources into local machine and use some script which fetches remote sources to local ones using MD5 or other algorithms. It shouldn't be a problem to write that script even by yourself. Again, as @DevSolar says, it is not a task for CMake.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I guess that's a good idea and I'll end up doing just that. I just wanted to avoid reinventing something that already exists so I asked.

Comment: FWIW, my own sources are *always* non-local, because my `/home` resides on a fileserver in my basement. Sync'ed both my netbook and the fileserver to the same NTP server, no problems ([after I did the setup correctly](http://superuser.com/questions/1037449)). That's why I suggested sync'ing your system to the same NTP source as the cluster (which is most likely "more correct" in the first place).

Comment: You can use  `make -B`  instead of  `make clean / make -j`

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821319/make-only-build-something-if-the-sources-md5-checksum-was-changed

Comment: Did you try to share your files with the server with svn (or similar) ? Then the files will have the modification time from the server, not from your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Right, so knowing that CMake / `make` does not do what I want and I don't want the hassle of synchronizing the time of my machine to the target, I came up with the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

touch src_hash.md5

echo -n make "$@" > mymake.sh

find `pwd`/../src `pwd`/../include -print0 | 
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f; do 
        if [[ ! -d "$f" ]]; then
            MD5=`md5sum "$f" | awk -v fn="$f" '{ print "\"" fn "\" " $1; }'`
            echo $MD5 >> src_hash.md5.new

            OLDMD5=`grep -e "^\"$f\"" src_hash.md5`
            if [[ "$OLDMD5" == "" ]]; then
                echo "$MD5 -- [a new file]"
                continue # a new file, make can handle that well on its own
            fi

            HASH=`echo $MD5 | awk '{ print $2; }'`
            OLDHASH=`echo $OLDMD5 | awk '{ print $2; }'`
            if [[ "$HASH" != "$OLDHASH" ]]; then
                echo "$MD5 -- changed from $OLDHASH"
                echo -n " \"--what-if=${f}\"" >> mymake.sh
                # this is running elsewhere, can't pass stuff via variables
            fi
        fi
    done

touch src_hash.md5.new
mv src_hash.md5.new src_hash.md5

echo using: `cat mymake.sh`
echo >> mymake.sh # add a newline
chmod +x mymake.sh
./mymake.sh
rm -f mymake.sh
```

This keeps a list of source file hashes in `src_hash.md5` and at each time it runs it compares the current files to those hashes (and updates the list accordingly).

At the end, it calls `make`, passing any arguments you give to the script (such as `-j`). It makes use of the `--what-if=` switch which tells `make` to act like the given file changed - that way the dependences of build targets on sources / headers are handled elegantly.

You might want to also pass the path to source / include files as arguments so that those wouldn't be hardcoded inside.

Or one more iteration on the said script, using `touch` to change and restore the file timestamps for situations when `make` is extra stubborn about not rebuilding anything:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -d ../src ]]; then
    >&2 echo "error: ../src is not a directory or does not exist"
    exit -1
fi
if [[ ! -d ../include ]]; then
    >&2 echo "error: ../include is not a directory or does not exist"
    exit -1
fi

echo "Scanning for changed files in ../src and ../include"

touch src_hash.md5 # in case this runs for the first time

rm -f mymaketouch.sh
rm -f mymakerestore.sh
touch mymaketouch.sh
touch mymakerestore.sh

echo -n make "$@" > mymake.sh

CWD="`pwd`"
find ../src ../include -print0 | 
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f; do 
        if [[ ! -d "$f" ]]; then
            fl=`readlink -f "$CWD/$f"`

            MD5=`md5sum "$fl" | awk -v fn="$fl" '{ print "\"" fn "\" " $1; }'`
            HASH=`echo $MD5 | awk '{ print $2; }'`
            echo $MD5 >> src_hash.md5.new

            OLDMD5=`grep -e "^\"$fl\"" src_hash.md5`
            OLDHASH=`echo $OLDMD5 | awk '{ print $2; }'`
            if [[ "$OLDMD5" == "" ]]; then
                echo "$f $HASH -- [a new file]"
                continue # a new file, make can handle that well on its own
            fi

            if [[ "$HASH" != "$OLDHASH" ]]; then
                echo "$f $HASH -- changed from $OLDHASH"

                echo "touch -m \"$fl\"" >> mymaketouch.sh # will touch it and change modification time
                stat "$fl" -c "touch -m -d \"%y\" \"%n\"" >> mymakerestore.sh # will restore it later on so that we do not run into problems when copying newer from a different system

                echo -n " \"--what-if=$fl\"" >> mymake.sh
                # this is running elsewhere, can't pass stuff via variables
            fi
        fi
    done

echo using: `cat mymake.sh`
echo >> mymake.sh # add a newline
echo 'exit $?' >> mymake.sh

chmod +x mymaketouch.sh
chmod +x mymakerestore.sh
chmod +x mymake.sh

control_c() # run if user hits control-c
{
    echo -en "\nrestoring modification times\n"
    ./mymakerestore.sh
    rm -f mymaketouch.sh
    rm -f mymakerestore.sh
    rm -f mymake.sh
    rm -f src_hash.md5.new 
    exit -1
}

trap control_c SIGINT

./mymaketouch.sh
./mymake.sh
RETVAL=$?
./mymakerestore.sh
rm -f mymaketouch.sh
rm -f mymakerestore.sh
rm -f mymake.sh

touch src_hash.md5.new # in case there was nothing new
mv src_hash.md5.new src_hash.md5
# do it now in case someone hits ctrl+c mid-build and not all files are built

exit $RETVAL
```

Or even run hashing in parallel in case you are building a large project:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -d ../src ]]; then
    >&2 echo "error: ../src is not a directory or does not exist"
    exit -1
fi
if [[ ! -d ../include ]]; then
    >&2 echo "error: ../include is not a directory or does not exist"
    exit -1
fi

echo "Scanning for changed files in ../src and ../include"

touch src_hash.md5 # in case this runs for the first time

rm -f mymaketouch.sh
rm -f mymakerestore.sh
touch mymaketouch.sh
touch mymakerestore.sh

echo -n make "$@" > mymake.sh

CWD="`pwd`"
rm -f src_hash.md5.new # will use ">>", make sure to remove the file
find ../src ../include -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f; do
        if [[ ! -d "$f" ]]; then
            fl="$CWD/$f"
            (echo `md5sum "$f" | awk -v fn="$fl" '{ print "\"" fn "\" " $1; }'` ) & # parallel, echo is atomic (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926616/is-echo-atomic-when-writing-single-lines)
            # run in parallel (remove the ampersand if you run into trouble)
        fi
    done >> src_hash.md5.new # >> is atomic but > wouldn't be
# this is fast

cat src_hash.md5 > src_hash.md5.diff
echo separator >> src_hash.md5.diff
cat src_hash.md5.new >> src_hash.md5.diff
# make a compound file for awk (could also read the other file in awk but this seems simpler right now)

cat src_hash.md5.diff | awk 'BEGIN { FS="\""; had_sep = 0; }
    {
        if(!had_sep && $1 == "separator")
            had_sep = 1;
        else {
            sub(/[[:space:]]/, "", $3);
            if(!had_sep)
                old_hashes[$2] = $3;
            else {
                f = $2;
                if((idx = index(f, "../")) != 0)
                    f = substr(f, idx, length(f) - idx + 1);
                if($2 in old_hashes) {
                    if(old_hashes[$2] != $3)
                        print "\"" f "\" " $3 " -- changed from " old_hashes[$2];
                } else
                    print "\"" f "\" -- a new file " $3;
            }
        }
    }'
# print verbose for the user only

cat src_hash.md5.diff | awk 'BEGIN { FS="\""; had_sep = 0; }
    {
        if(!had_sep && $1 == "separator")
            had_sep = 1;
        else {
            sub(/[[:space:]]/, "", $3);
            if(!had_sep)
                old_hashes[$2] = $3;
            else {
                if($2 in old_hashes) {
                    if(old_hashes[$2] != $3)
                        printf($2 "\0"); /* use \0 as a line separator for the below loop */
                }
            }
        }
    }' |
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' fl; do
        echo "touch -m \"$fl\"" >> mymaketouch.sh # will touch it and change modification time
        stat "$fl" -c "touch -m -d \"%y\" \"%n\"" >> mymakerestore.sh # will restore it later on so that we do not run into problems when copying newer from a different system

        echo -n " \"--what-if=$fl\"" >> mymake.sh
        # this is running elsewhere, can't pass stuff via variables
    done
# run again, handle files that require change

rm -f src_hash.md5.diff

echo using: `cat mymake.sh`
echo >> mymake.sh # add a newline
echo 'exit $?' >> mymake.sh

chmod +x mymaketouch.sh
chmod +x mymakerestore.sh
chmod +x mymake.sh

control_c() # run if user hits control-c
{
    echo -en "\nrestoring modification times\n"
    ./mymakerestore.sh
    rm -f mymaketouch.sh
    rm -f mymakerestore.sh
    rm -f mymake.sh
    rm -f src_hash.md5.new 
    exit -1
}

trap control_c SIGINT

./mymaketouch.sh
./mymake.sh
RETVAL=$?
./mymakerestore.sh
rm -f mymaketouch.sh
rm -f mymakerestore.sh
rm -f mymake.sh

touch src_hash.md5.new # in case there was nothing new
mv src_hash.md5.new src_hash.md5
# do it now in case someone hits ctrl+c mid-build and not all files are built

exit $RETVAL
```

Comment: @ComicSansMS thanks for the fix, didn't know bash was supported like that. I was mostl y leaving `.sh` behind fot the "future SO highlighter".