# CMake+git: check file sha rather than timestamp

Tags: c++, git, build, cmake

As far as I know, CMake checks the time stamp of a source file to detect if it is outdated and needs to be rebuild (and with it, all files including it). When switching branches in a large git repository, this can causes problems.

Let's say I have one source folder and two build directories (build1 and build2), which correspond to two different branches (branch1 and branch2)

```
   project
      +-- src
      +-- branch1_build
      +-- branch2_build
```

Say my two branches have few differences, in few files; mostly, they only differ for some configuration option, all encapsulated in a `config.h` file, generated by the `CONFIGURE_FILE` command in cmake. The source files for the two `config.h` files (the `config.h.in`, as it is often called) are different. For instance, one branch introduces a new subfolder, which can be activated with a config-time option, which gets put in `config.h.in` with something like `#cmakedefine HAVE_NEW_FEATURE_FOLDER`. In such a scenario, when switching branches in the source folder, this happens: cmake recognizes that something changed in the `config.h.in` file, so it runs again; by running again, it generates a new `config.h` file; since `config.h` has a new time stamp, all files that includes it (directly or indirectly) end up being recompiled.

Now, if I alternatively switch between branch1 and branch2 in the source folder (cause I'm working on both branches every day), two consecutive `make` commands issued in the same build folder (either branch1_build or branch2_build) will trigger a full recompilation, since, although `config.h` has not changed in content, its time stamp has changed, so cmake flags it has changed.

My question is: what options do I have to avoid this? Or, better phrased, how can I avoid recompiling a source-build tree pair that is in fact unchanged since the last build, while also minimizing the changes to the source code?

The only solution I can think of is to execute `CONFIGURE_FILE` on `config.h.in`, with output `config.h.tmp`; compare `config.h.tmp` with `config.h`, and, *only* if different, copy `config.h.tmp` to `config.h`. However, this seems clumsy, and overcomplicated. I hoped cmake already had a mechanism for this, perhaps hidden under some options/variations of `CONFIGURE_FILE`...

Assuming this is not yet possible, I was wondering how complicated it would be for cmake to check the sha (rather than the timestamp) of a particular file when deciding whether it is *outdated* or not, and comparing it with the sha of a previous build (yes, the word *outdated* has *date* in it, but let's not get into enlish vocabulary discussions here). I imagine this is more expensive, so I would think that, if possible at all, this behavior should not be the default, and the user should use *sparingly* this feature, by explicitly tagging a file as *check_sha_not_time* kind of file. In the example above, the user would tag `config.h` as *check_sha_not_time*, and avoid recompilation of pretty much the whole library.

Note 0: I know little of how cmake internally works, so my suggestion of using sha rather than timestamp could be completely crazy and/or impossible given cmake implementation. I apologize for that. But that's why one asks things here, cause he/she doesn't know, right?

Note 1: I also tried using `ccache`, but unsuccessfully. Perhaps I need to use some particular flag or configuration option in ccache to trigger this capability.

Note 2: I want to avoid duplicating the source folder.

Edit:Tsyvarev's comment is right, so this question can be closed. See the comments for further details.

Comment: [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org) helps a lot in that case.

Comment: AFAIK, `cmake` does not have much to do with this. This is a 'feature' of ninja/make, or whatever build system you are using.  It seems logical and possible to me to use hashing instead of date. See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/319359/why-incremental-builds-in-make-dont-use-hashing-algorithms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make: only build something if the source's md5 checksum was changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821319/make-only-build-something-if-the-sources-md5-checksum-was-changed)

Comment: Would something like [`CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/1792) help to temporarily suppress the "do I need to re-generate" check of CMake? Unfortunately this is work in progress for Unix makefile generators.

Comment: For me, `CONFIGURE_FILE` changes timestamp of the resulted file only if its **content** should be **changed**. (Tested on Linux with "Unix Makefiles" generator). Which generator (and OS) do you use? Is there some special about the filesystem which hosts your source/binary directories? (E.g. with shared folders timestamps behaves strange some time).

Comment: bartgol can you either reply to the people who tried to help you or close this question? as it is, this question has been left here to suffer for four years now.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think you are correct. It's been a while, so I can't recall what the deal was with the project that got me to write this question, but ever since I have noticed the same behavior you describe: if the content does not change, cmake does not replace the file, hence doesn't change the timestamp.

I will close the question as resolved.